# Query failing on Oracle 12c and 18c when changing NLS_SORT to BINARY_CI

Tags: oracle-12c

I have the following query which correctly returns records when I execute it via code or Oracle SQL Developer.

```
SELECT TABLE_T.COL_P,
       1234 AS COL_C,
       TABLE_T.COL_D,
       SUM(SOME_COLUMN) Value
FROM TABLE_T
INNER JOIN TABLE_E E ON TABLE_T.COL_P = E.COL_P
AND TABLE_T.COL_C = E.COL_C
AND TABLE_T.COL_CC = E.COL_CC
AND TABLE_T.COL_CL = E.COL_CL
INNER JOIN TABLE_C C1 ON C1.COL_P = E.COL_P
AND C1.COL_C = E.COL_C
INNER JOIN TABLE_C C2 ON C2.COL_P = C1.COL_P
AND C2.COL_CX = C1.COL_CX
AND C2.COL_CY = C1.COL_CY
AND C2.COL_CZ = C1.COL_CZ
WHERE TABLE_T.COL_P = 'Some Text'
  AND C2.COL_C = 1234
  AND TABLE_T.COL_CL IN
    (SELECT COL_CL
     FROM TABLE_CL
     WHERE COL_P = 'Some Text'
       AND ((COL_CLTYPE = 'VALUE_A')
            OR (COL_CLTYPE = 'VALUE_B')
            OR (COL_CLTYPE = 'VALUE_C')
            OR (COL_CLTYPE = 'VALUE_D')) )
GROUP BY TABLE_T.COL_P,
         TABLE_T.COL_D
```

However, it fails to return records once I execute the following session commands:

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP = LINGUISTIC;

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT = BINARY_CI;

This problem only occurs when I'm running against an Oracle 12c or 18c database.

It works find with/without the session commands when running against an Oracle 12C R2 or 11g database.

I've already checked the Explain Plan for 12c/18c and 12cR2 and its creating the same plan.

I found out that by adding an ORDER BY clause to the query (ORDER BY TABLE_T.COL_D, it resolves the problem.

Any ideas on what might be causing this problem?

I know the ORDER BY solution works, but I'd like to know what the underlying cause is and if there's a better solution to it.

Comment: How can an `ORDER BY` clause influence the number of results?

Comment: It shouldn't, I guess it's an internal problem with Oracle. I got an answer from another post that it might be related to Oracle Bug 27416997.